# How to link an iOS static library that uses C++ vectors, for use in Delphi XE7?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, delphi

I build a static library in xCode that I must use in Delphi XE7 for the iOS platform.  The library is written in C++ and uses vectors.  The functions I need to use in Delphi are all pure C functions (export "C").  They are recognized by the linker, but there is one linking error I can't get rid of :

```
"  Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:    __ZNKSt3__120__vector_base_commonILb1EE20__throw_length_errorEv", referenced from:..."
```

To distinguish this problem from other possible issues, I made a simple project, that uses vectors and got the same problem.  If I remove the use of vectors in that simple project, all goes well, linking and running on my iPad through a FireMonkey project in Delphi with iOS target.

I also built a simple application as an xCode project, using the same C++ library.  The project links and runs in xCode without doing anything special about it (I guess xCode links the application against the correct C++ library automatically).

I tried to add libc++.dylib and/or libstdc++.dylib to the xCode project, but there is the warning that these are dynamic libraries so they are ignored when linking the static library.  I tried to locate a static version of these libraries but couldn't find them anywhere (do they exist ?).

So my question is : how can I add the C++ library to the static library I build with xCode, so that XE7 will not complain about this ?

Edited :  I get the following xCode command line for the last file compiled (I do not see any command line with the Build step) :

```
"CompileC /Users/admin/Documents/xCode\ Derived\ Data/TartiniLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/TartiniLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Kiss_Wrapper.o Sources/Kiss_Wrapper.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/admin/Documents/iOSTartini/TartiniLib
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DUSE_KISS=1 -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Users/admin/Documents/xCode\ Derived\ Data/TartiniLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/TartiniLib.build/TartiniLib-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/admin/Documents/xCode\ Derived\ Data/TartiniLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/TartiniLib.build/TartiniLib-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/admin/Documents/xCode\ Derived\ Data/TartiniLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/TartiniLib.build/TartiniLib-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/admin/Documents/xCode\ Derived\ Data/TartiniLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/TartiniLib.build/TartiniLib-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/admin/Documents/xCode\ Derived\ Data/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/admin/Documents/xCode\ Derived\ Data/TartiniLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/TartiniLib.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/admin/Documents/xCode\ Derived\ Data/TartiniLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/TartiniLib.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/admin/Documents/xCode\ Derived\ Data/Debug-iphoneos -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/admin/Documents/xCode\ Derived\ Data/TartiniLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/TartiniLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Kiss_Wrapper.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/admin/Documents/xCode\ Derived\ Data/TartiniLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/TartiniLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Kiss_Wrapper.dia -c /Users/admin/Documents/iOSTartini/TartiniLib/Sources/Kiss_Wrapper.cpp -o /Users/admin/Documents/xCode\ Derived\ Data/TartiniLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/TartiniLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Kiss_Wrapper.o"
```

Comment: These kinds of things may be specific to certain versions of compilers, stl source, build settings, etc. Much of the STL is header only, which means there may not be a static library implementing the length_error class or vector, depending on your implementation. What version of XCode are you using, and can you include an example of XCode's compile and link commands from the log

Comment: Can't you rewrite the vector code using TList<T> or TArray<T>?

Comment: @Johan: the library in question is compiled in xCode C++ and uses vectors internally, not exposed in the public API that Delphi will be accessing.  Being a static library, any dependent libraries, like STL implementations and such, have to be linked as well. Changing to `TList` or `TArray` is not an option as those are Embarcadero RTL classes, but the library is not compiled in Delphi or C++Builder.

Comment: @JVene: I use xCode 6.4 to build the static library.  How do I get the compile & link command ?  I never used the command line tool...

Comment: @Dominique: First, I should add to the comments thus far, expanding on my first point. std::vector is a template class, written inline. This means that code to operate a vector is generated when you instantiate vectors of a particular type. (i.e. std::vector<int> and std::vector<double> generate two bodies of code). This won't be in a pre-built library, especially if you create a vector for a type you declare, like std::vector<myStruct>. It LOOKS like what you're missing is code for the EXCEPTION, not the vector. More in a moment on compile/link command (limited space here)

Comment: @Dominique: To see the compile/link commands, view the report navigator. When you build, the navigator list on the left shows the build steps. Select the ones that say build, to show details on the main window to the right. In that window, to the right, right click and choose to expand all transcripts. That shows you the command line tools XCode used to build, and the settings included. More later on what we're looking for in that, but you'll see what libraries are included in the build, for example.

Comment: @Dominique: Are any of your source files ending in .m? If so, change them to .mm and retry. Similar of they're ending in .c, change to .cpp and retry the build. Also check build settings for "C++ Language Dialect" and "C++ Standard Library". Set them both to "Compiler Default". Also experiment with build setting "C++ Standard Library", try "libc++", then "libstdc++". Ultimately there MIGHT be binary incompatibility between XE7 and XCode 6.4. You MIGHT need an older XCode.

Comment: @JVene: I will try combinations of what you say.  I put here above the xCode command line I found for the last file (I can't find the command line with Build?).

Comment: I'm not sure it is related, but there are also a set of warnings, which I could not find what they could possibly mean :
   "  ld: warning: unknown dwarf DW_FORM_strp (offset=0xFFFFEB3F) is too big in TartiniLib-Device.a(Pimpl.o)"
Would that be a clue on what is happening ?

Comment: Well, "unknown dwarf DW_FORM_str" is a reference to some problem in debugging information. It could be incompatible formats of dwarf (there's dwarf2 and dwarf3, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a symbol from the lib in your Delphi code, just so the linker knows about the lib. You can add this to one of the Delphi units, for example:

function nothrow: pointer; cdecl; external '/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib';

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I am not sure how to determine the correct name to put in :  I tried the exact name in the link error : "function __ZNSt3__16vectorIfNS_9allocatorIfEEE21__push_back_slow_pathIRKfEEvOT_: pointer; cdecl; external '/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib';" in the implementation part and also "function __ZNSt3__16vectorIfNS_9allocatorIfEEE21__push_back_slow_pathIRKfEEvOT_: pointer; cdecl;" in the interface part.
However, the error stays the same.  I tried a few of these symbols.  I can find several instances of each with a text search in my library.a  from xCode, with HexEdit

Comment: You don't need to use the functions the linker complains about, any symbol exported by the library will do. Did you try 'nothow'?

Comment: Yes, I tried first the line of code you told me, but the error was still there.